# Smart contract listeners

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, web3j, quorum

I want to develop a method in a smart contract that act as a listener,
what i mean is when i use eth.sendTransaction(from:, to:@ of smart contract) it will be executed, without calling any smart contract's methods, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need a method which can be called without  transaction. You need to add keyword `constant` to your function name and it will not modify the state, so you can run it without transactions.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract c{
    function f() constant returns(uint){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If you need a `fallback function` which was my second idea, please follow the [manual](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Ethereum-Development-Best-Practices/wiki/Fallback-functions-and-the-fundamental-limitations-of-using-send()-in-Ethereum-&-Solidity) how to create functions that are triggered when the function signature does not match any of the available functions in a Solidity contract.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you are looking for but it could help others

[Bloopi](https://bloopi.io/docs/index#balance-3) allows you to subscribe to the balance function of an ERC20 token contract:

```
args = {contract_id:"", wallet_address:""}
Bloopi::API::Token.balance(args)

{
  "balance": 9999939500000,
  "contract_address": "0xAF0f6FD6D97bf619bF3b1bEEa80175F2c7F5DD91"
}
```